# Ignite durable memory settings

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I want to understand when a cache is created with native persistence enabled, will it store the data in the defined data region/RAM and in the disk at the same time? Is there any way I can restrict the disk utilization for storing the data?

Additionally, in a cluster of 3 due to any reason the disk got full for one of the nodes and there is not enough memory available, what will be the impact on the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data will be stored both in RAM and on the disk. I does not have to fit in RAM at the same time.

If you run out of disk space, your persistent store will likely be corrupted.

Comment: thanks for the information. However, is that possible to restrict the disk utilization for persistence for a particular cache?

Comment: You can create a non-persistent region for some caches, or you can configure expiration policy for your data.

Comment: If I configure expiration policy, will the data delete both from memory and disk as per the expiry duration?

Comment: No, eviction makes sense only for non-persisted regions. There is just no point for eviction if you have native persistence enabled. When your data fills in available RAM, a  page replacement process comes and swaps some data pages on disk, thus freeing available RAM memory. Whereas with an eviction policy your data will be lost.

Comment: Please check https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies - contrary to eviction, expiry does indeed remove data from both disk and memory @sandipbhowmik

Comment: @alamar As per the doc https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies do I need to set the expiry policy for each data region or per cache?

Comment: You should set it by cache or even on by entry basis.